# table of contents empty if compiled with LuaLaTex

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex

I have a weird problem with LuaLaTex. The following minimal example works fine with either pdflatex and xelatex, as the contents page is filled with all the chapters. If I compile the same example, from scratch, using lualatex, the contents page is empty.
Note that lualatex does generate the .toc file correctly, but it doesn't seem to use it. I wonder if it's a bug or if I'm missing something.

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)
```

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
This is the first chapter.

\chapter{Second}
This is the second.

\chapter{Third}
And the third.

\end{document}
```

Edit: I've just realized that if I run lualatex twice, then the contents page is filled in.

Log of first run:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2018.4.18)  30 APR 2018 09:32
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using cache: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gen
eric)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfloa
d/fontloader-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.125 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: /home/fede/
.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.l
uc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
No file test.aux.

\openout1 = test.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(load luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/o
tl/lmroman17-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-bold.luc)
No file test.toc.
\tf@toc=\write3

\openout3 = test.toc
[1


{/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}](l
oad luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmromanslant10-regular.luc) [2

]
Chapter 1.
[3] [4

]
Chapter 2.
[5] [6

]
Chapter 3.
[7] [8

]
Chapter 4.
[9] (./test.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 254 strings out of 494480
 100000,89155 words of node,token memory allocated
 353 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:30,3:10,4:2,5:23,6:42,7:30,8:3,9:9,10:1,11:3
 4468 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 20 fonts using 1381871 bytes
 22i,4n,17p,107b,165s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmromanslant10-regular.o
tf></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-bold.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (9 pages, 14107 bytes).

PDF statistics: 53 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 32 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Log of second run:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2018.4.18)  30 APR 2018 09:34
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using cache: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gen
eric)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfloa
d/fontloader-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.115 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: /home/fede/
.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.l
uc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(load luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/o
tl/lmroman17-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-bold.luc)
(./test.toc(load luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/lmroman10-bold.luc))
\tf@toc=\write3

\openout3 = test.toc
 [1


{/home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}](l
oad luc: /home/fede/.local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmromanslant10-regular.luc) [2

]
Chapter 1.
[3] [4

]
Chapter 2.
[5] [6

]
Chapter 3.
[7] [8

]
Chapter 4.
[9] (./test.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 266 strings out of 494480
 100000,89155 words of node,token memory allocated
 353 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:50,3:25,4:2,5:24,6:45,7:56,8:3,9:21,10:1,11:3
 4469 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 21 fonts using 1513559 bytes
 22i,4n,17p,107b,165s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmromanslant10-regular.o
tf></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bold.otf></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-bold.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (9 pages, 17616 bytes).

PDF statistics: 60 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 36 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Works fine here. Show the log-file of the second lualatex run.

Comment: No problem here. But I have lualatex 1.0.7.

Comment: I've just edited the question and added the log files.

Comment: Further to above, if I add a new chapter, the chapter appears in the toc only after running lualatex twice. Do you experience the same?

Comment: The log-file are not complete. Are you killing the run? That you need to run twice is normal. That's the way the toc always works.

Comment: No, I did not kill the run. I just cut out the last lines. I'll edit it again.

Comment: So the problem is solved right? You simply didn't run twice?

Comment: the behaviour you describe is unrelated to luatex, it always takes multiple runs, whether you use luatex or pdftex

Comment: David, you are right. Good to know